How can we query collections with DBRef in Quarkus Mongodb PANACHE extension?
We are using the Quarkus MongoDB Panache extension as an ORM for our application. We have two collections: Profile and User. When I query the profile using the user id, I get the results, but I am unable to map it to the Entity class.
Document query = new Document("user.$id", new ObjectId(userId));

I followed the official guide mentioned here and checked the SOF post here. Even when I tried with the Mongo Client, I encountered the same problem.
Can someone please share the sample code to map DBRef field to Java Pojo?
Profile collection
{
    "profile_name": "Ragav"
    "user" : { "$ref" : "user", "$id" : "001" },
    "created_by" : "system",
    "created_date" : "2024-04-12T05:43:26.521+0000",
    
}


User collection
{
    "id": "001",
    "login":"ragav",
    "password":"jdhfsahgfhghfg"
}


You have to do it manually:

var children = ParentEntity.findById(id).children
   .stream()
   .map(ChildEntity::findById)
   .toList();

Or use the in-operator:

import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.in;

public static List<ChildEntity> findIdIn(List<ObjectId> childIds) {
   return find(in("_id", childIds)).list();
}

Then it becomes like this:

var childIds = ParentEntity.findById(id).children;
var children = ChildEntity.findIdIn(childIds);

